# ReactJS OnKeyPress to trigger a button press

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, onclick, onkeypress

I'm very new to **ReactJS** and I'm just trying to do some small things to understand more.

I was wondering if the **OnKeyPress** can trigger a button press. I've seen a few *similar* questions but what the **OnKeyPress** triggered was just a console.log or an alert. So I wasn't sure how to trigger the button press.

This is what I have so far:

```
class Form extends React.Component {
  onButtonPress = (e) => {
    // this is just an example of what happens when the button is pressed.
    this.setState({isClicked: true});
  }

  keyPress = (event) => {
    if (event.key == 'Enter'){
      // How would I trigger the button that is in the render? I have this so far.
      this.onButtonPress();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="fieldForm">
          <input
            value={name}
            type="name"
            onKeyPress={this.keyPress}
          />
        </div>
        <Button onClick={this.onButtonPress}>Submit</Button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Please note that I didn't include everything in here such as the constructor, props, or the state object attributes.

The purpose of this is to make it look like the button has been clicked. When the button is clicked, it'll show a small loading sign on the button. I want the same thing to happen if I were to press enter (with the loading sign on the button, that's why I want the button pressed).

Is this possible?

Comment: pretty sure that the `event.key` value is all lowercase

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Programmatically triggering DOM events is not something you should do unless you have very specific needs.

Both `onKeyPress` and `onClick` are event handlers, you can do anything you want when an event happens. I would just call a function that sets the state you want from both handlers.

Here's an example:

```
class Form extends React.Component {
  handleFormSubmit = () => {
    this.setState({ isClicked: true });
  };

  handleButtonPress = () => {
    this.handleFormSubmit();
  };

  handleKeyPress = event => {
    if (event.key == 'Enter') {
      this.handleFormSubmit();
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="fieldForm">
          <input value={name} type="name" onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress} />
        </div>
        <Button onClick={this.handleButtonPress} loading={this.state.Load}>
          Submit
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: When you say specific needs, what would that entail? At what point can I trigger DOM events?

Comment: For example if you are using a third-party library that only reacts to DOM events. In any case, something like that should be rare. I would only do it if it's the only choice.

Comment: @chakolatemilk read about [refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#when-to-use-refs).

Answer (score 3):

In case you have **no other way** and you **should** click on this element for some vague reason and the method that **[elas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4565207/elas) said didn't work** for you. try this:

```
  onButtonPress = (e) => {
    console.log('hi hi')
  }

  handleKeyPress = (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      this.refs.but.click()
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Layout>
        <div>
          <div className="fieldForm">
            <input
              value={'name'}
              type="name"
              onKeyPress={(e) => this.handleKeyPress(e)}
            />
          </div>
          <Button onClick={this.onButtonPress} ref="but">Submit</Button>
        </div>
      </Layout>
    )
  }
```

Comment: In case you are wondering why I'm asking you to try other methods first, it is because using [refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#when-to-use-refs) is not a very wise move in react and it's somehow anti-pattern since you are manipulating actual DOM.